# write list of word from web site to txt file

Tags: python

I want to make text file contain many Arabic word so I think to open website in python by: urlopen function  and save the word in list then export it to text file .
I'm new in python any help I will be  thankful

Comment: You just want a list of arabic words? How about an arabic dictionary?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. What's the text file and the website thing supposed to mean? Is there a website of words?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `urllib` and `re`. What have you tried so far? (code)

Answer (score 1):

to save a file from the web:

```
import urllib2

u = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.your-url-here.com/filename.txt')
f = open('myfile.txt', 'w')
f.write(u.read())
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Extract the html from the website that contains the text
2. clear it of html tags and symbols
3. extract words.
4. filter out the noise

for the 2-nd and 3-rd point you can use nltk.
Here is an example how it could be implemented:

```
import nltk
import urllib2
u = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')# replace google with your arabic site of interest
UnwantedSymbols='|&;.,-!'#real words don't contain these symbols, add yours
html=u.read()
raw = nltk.clean_html(html)
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
filename='arabicwords.txt'
f=open(filename,'w')
for token in tokens:
    write=True
    for symbol in UnwantedSymbols:
        if symbol in token:
            write=False
            break
    if write:
        f.write(token+'\n')# if no unwanted symbol was encountered, then write the word to the file
f.close()
```